# All statements are set when using if

Tags: javascript, jquery

Something wrong with my code, all the statements are set 
I want when sum is in a specific range, each ID will be added a css

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
      var sum = 0;
      var numberQA = 4
      $('.skillA:checkbox').click(function() {
        sum = 0;
        $('.skillA:checkbox:checked').each(function(idx, elm) {
          // idx: index position of selector, elm = this selector,
          sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
        });
        // average = sum / numberQA;   
        $('#totalSkillA').html(sum);

        if (4 <= sum && sum <= 6) {
          $('#communicationSkill1').css({
            "backgroundColor": "#087cb7",
            "color": "white"
          })
        } else if (7 <= sum && sum <= 10) {
          $('#communicationSkill2').css({
            "backgroundColor": "#087cb7",
            "color": "white"
          })
        } else if (11 <= sum && sum <= 13) {
          $('#communicationSkill3').css({
            "backgroundColor": "#087cb7",
            "color": "white"
          })
        } else {
          $('#communicationSkill4').css({
            "backgroundColor": "#087cb7",
            "color": "white"
          })
        }

      });
```

Comment: Sr, It should be not the same, and the tds are still highlighted for all

Comment: Just `return;` from all the conditions to skip the remaining.

Comment: Can you provide a small example with the snippet function? Just add in some of those checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works except I think you're expecting the highlighted elements to be unhighlighted when another checkbox is clicked. That line was missing so I added it. I also used a proper class and used `addClass` instead.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var sum = 0;
  var numberQA = 4
  $('.skillA:checkbox').click(function() {
    sum = 0;
    $('.skillA:checkbox:checked').each(function(idx, elm) {
      sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
    });

    // remove the highlight
    $('div').removeClass('highlight')
    if (4 <= sum && sum <= 6) {
      $('#communicationSkill1').addClass('highlight');
    } else if (7 <= sum && sum <= 10) {
      $('#communicationSkill2').addClass('highlight');
    } else if (11 <= sum && sum <= 13) {
      $('#communicationSkill3').addClass('highlight');
    } else {
      $('#communicationSkill4').addClass('highlight');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: #087cb7;
  color: white;
}

div {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="skillA" type="checkbox" value="1">1
<input class="skillA" type="checkbox" value="4">2
<input class="skillA" type="checkbox" value="8">3
<input class="skillA" type="checkbox" value="11">4
<br/><br/>
<div id="communicationSkill1">communicationSkill1</div>
<div id="communicationSkill2">communicationSkill2</div>
<div id="communicationSkill3">communicationSkill3</div>
<div id="communicationSkill4">communicationSkill4</div>
```

Comment: Thank youSo what if I have another checkboxB 
$('.skillB:checkbox').click(function() {
        sum = 0;
        $('.skillB:checkbox:checked').each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
        });    
  // average = sum / numberQA;   
  $('#totalSkillB').html(sum);  
  
    });

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set  $('#communicationSkill1').css({"background-color":"#087cb7", "color":"white"})

Please replace backgroundColor --> background-color

Comment: use background-color for the css property.